# Cancel ng-swipe-right on child

Tags: angularjs, swipe

In my angular application, the body has a `ng-swipe` right and left to toggle a sidebar. The problem is when in my page I have a scrollable horizontal DIV. It won't scroll because of the swipe of the body.

```
<body ng-swipe-right="sidebar = true" ng-swipe-left="sidebar = false">
    <div class="scrollable-x">long content that overflow on x</div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to prevent from swiping and to let the scroll of the child element?

I tried to set `$event.stopPropagation()` on the swipe of the div so the scrollbar is not toggled anymore but the content won't scroll.

Any idea?

Comment: I have got an idea - why not to create a plnkr/fiddle/whatever?

Comment: This is quite an old question, I'm not sure the user is still active. I'm interested in a solution, I'll create a fiddle now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wmc75s4y/ Try scrolling from left-right right-left inside the yellow box.

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE

Looked at *allenhwkim*'s answer and indeed he is correct, that `$event`'s propagation can be easily stopped. I took it for granted (without checking), that attaching `ng-swipe-*` directive to other element will start firing separate events. I was clearly wrong.

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yve2rLkr/6/) is updated fiddle.

<del>The below answer is basically rubbish.</del>

There is still one problem with `stopPropagation` -- the mouse up event seems not to fire.

---

The most elegant solution would be to decorate the `ng-swipe-*` directives or `$swipe` service -- but looking into their code and I do not think it is possible.

Other option would be to create your own directive, that would manually attach `ng-swipe-*`, take care of the compilation process and provide desired functionality. Surely, bit complicated.

What I came up with is a *quick hack*. The idea is to add an attribute to an element whose descendants should not fire the `ng-swipe-*`.

#### js

```
myApp.value('shouldFire', function(element){
     var update = true;

        // strange enough $event.fromElement is always null
        var current = element;
        while(current && current != document.body){
            if(current.getAttribute('swipe')=='cancel'){
                update = false;
                break;
            }
            current = current.parentElement;
        }

        return update;
})

function MyCtrl($scope, shouldFire) {
    $scope.sidebar = false;

    $scope.updateSidebar = function($event, show){

        var element = $event.toElement || $event.srcElement; 
        shouldFire(element) && ($scope.sidebar = show);

    }
}
```

#### html

```
<div class="cont" ng-swipe-right="updateSidebar($event, true)"
    ng-swipe-left="updateSidebar($event, false)">

...

<div class="pan-container" panhandler=""
   content-width="500px" swipe="cancel">
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yve2rLkr/4/)

---

#### caution

1. in android's chrome.v.39 *angular-panhandler* is broken.
2. <del>`$event` stores a proper touch event (android's chrome) or a custom event (desktop's chrome); in the latter case `$event.fromElement` is always `null`.</del>
3. The proposed solution is a quick hack -- it is neither elegant nor general. Nonetheless, theoretically it could be possible to support multi `ng-swipe-*` handlers by setting different values in `swipe` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`$event.stopProgagation()` must work. I don't know why yours not work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/AqczfhAVGMXNOcJij0JE?p=preview

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngTouch']);
  app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.void = function(evt){
      evt.stopPropagation();
    }
  });
```

The common sense to me is that swiping and scroll left/right are different.

swiping is about moving fast. If you do not move fast. it's not swiping.
When you scroll slowly, swiping does not happen.

I think all users know about this(maybe not). 
If not, I would recommend  UX approach to let the user scroll slowly 
by showing some button or whatever, and leaving swipe as it is.

Anyhow, there is a way to disabling swipe using `stopPropagation`

Let me know if this plnkr does not satisfy your requirement.

Comment: You are right about `stopPropagation`. I think you did not save your plnkr properly though. +1

Answer (score 0):

It's like this. In your scrollable element (usually it's the dom element you set as *overflow-x: scroll*), add **ng-swipe-right="preventScrollingFunction($event)"**, like so:

```
<div ng-swipe-right="preventScrollingFunction($event)">...</div>
```

Then, in the scope create the function:

```
$scope.preventScrollingFunction = function($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
}
```

That should do it!

Note: make sure the parameter for the function is exactly **$event**, as it is inyected by Angular and if you name it **$evt** or **$e** or whatever, it wont work.